# I Can't find my wife?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

In Minecraft Comes Alive it seems that I lost my wife. I have crafted the whistle and keep calling but only my daughter shows up. I tried gifting a wedding ring to another female villager (she had over 100 rep) but she said I should be ashamed because I'm already married.

How do I find my wife?

Answer (score 1):

The reason she is not coming back is because when your wife or child does not get enough attention, or your child does too many chores, they run away. But, thanks to the programming, you can change it to night so your wife/child comes back to their home point in your house/village. If you have not set a home point the child/wife always goes to the next nearest village. So, basically, if she does not come back, go find the closest village next to yours and you will find them! I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a couple things here. It's happened to me before.

- Your wife is either stuck somewhere and can't move
- Your wife has died and it the game doesn't recognize that
- It's just a glitch in the game

In the end it can be really hard to find her. But good luck sorry I could't help much!

Comment: IN what vicinity is she stuck in? 50x50? Or can she be anywhere?

Comment: She will probably be near where you saw her she's not going to be too far but she could be anywhere she could access